# Angular 11 - An unhandled exception occurred: NGCC failed

Tags: angular, npm

I have just upgraded my application from Angular version 10 to 11.

While the upgrade process went pretty much effortless, I can't seem to get my application running now.

When I try to execute `ng serve` I get the following error:

```
Error: Error on worker #1: Error: Debug Failure. Unhandled SyntaxKind: Unknown.
    at pipelineEmitWithHintWorker (/home/richinel/Sites/carlocksystems/carlocksystems.frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:114185:22)
    at pipelineEmitWithHint (/home/richinel/Sites/carlocksystems/carlocksystems.frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:113716:17)
    at pipelineEmitWithComments (/home/richinel/Sites/carlocksystems/carlocksystems.frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:117404:13)
    at pipelineEmit (/home/richinel/Sites/carlocksystems/carlocksystems.frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:113656:13)
    at emit (/home/richinel/Sites/carlocksystems/carlocksystems.frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:113629:13)
    at emitParameter (/home/richinel/Sites/carlocksystems/carlocksystems.frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:114422:13)
    at pipelineEmitWithHintWorker (/home/richinel/Sites/carlocksystems/carlocksystems.frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:113765:32)
    at pipelineEmitWithHint (/home/richinel/Sites/carlocksystems/carlocksystems.frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:113716:17)
    at pipelineEmitWithComments (/home/richinel/Sites/carlocksystems/carlocksystems.frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:117404:13)
    at pipelineEmit (/home/richinel/Sites/carlocksystems/carlocksystems.frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:113656:13)
    at ClusterMaster.onWorkerMessage (/home/richinel/Sites/carlocksystems/carlocksystems.frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/master.js:195:27)
    at /home/richinel/Sites/carlocksystems/carlocksystems.frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/master.js:55:95
    at ClusterMaster.<anonymous> (/home/richinel/Sites/carlocksystems/carlocksystems.frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/master.js:293:57)
    at step (/home/richinel/Sites/carlocksystems/carlocksystems.frontend/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:193:27)
    at Object.next (/home/richinel/Sites/carlocksystems/carlocksystems.frontend/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:174:57)
    at /home/richinel/Sites/carlocksystems/carlocksystems.frontend/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:167:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (/home/richinel/Sites/carlocksystems/carlocksystems.frontend/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:163:16)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/richinel/Sites/carlocksystems/carlocksystems.frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/cluster/master.js:287:32)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
An unhandled exception occurred: NGCC failed.
See "/tmp/ng-Frwt31/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Please find my `package.json` file below:

```
{
  "name": "carlocksystems",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "ec2-deploy-dev": "node ec2-deploy/ec2-deploy.dev.js",
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.14",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^9.1.15",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "@types/heremaps": "^3.1.8",
    "aes-js": "^3.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "chokidar": "^3.5.3",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^3.28.0",
    "ec2-deploy": "^2.2.1",
    "fortawesome": "0.0.1-security",
    "jquery.pointer-events-polyfill": "^0.2.4",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "msrcrypto": "^1.5.8",
    "ng-mocks": "^14.6.0",
    "ng2-heremaps": "^0.2.5",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^15.0.0",
    "ngx-file-drop": "^14.0.2",
    "ngx-image-compress": "^13.1.16",
    "ngx-smart-popover": "^1.4.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.0.0",
    "pkcs7": "^1.0.2",
    "read-excel-file": "^5.6.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "simple-crypto-js": "^3.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "unorm": "^1.6.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.2.19",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~11.2.14",
    "@ngneat/spectator": "^5.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "s3-deploy": "^1.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.6"
  }
}
```

Am I missing/overseeing something?

I already tried the following things (found in other posts):

- Removing and reinstalling NPM (including removing the `node_modules` folder).
- Removing the `package-lock.json` file.
- I also read something about disabling Ivy, but that just feels like a quick fix in stead of a correct solution to me.

Any help is appreciated.

*(PS: My current NodeJS version is v14.20.1. Please let me know if you need additional blocks of code).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there were several incompatible packages.

Basically, I checked the versions of all the packages in the `package.json` file and made sure they were the right versions for this version of Angular.
After every check I executed `npm install` and the list of errors started to disappear.

In my case, I installed the wrong versions of `ngx-cookie-service`, `ngx-image-compress`, `ngx-file-drop` and (somehow) `typescript`.

Should you run into a similar situation, please make sure that you installed the correct versions of the packages corresponding to the version of Angular.